# Prove that $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)$ takes exactly $n-1$ iteration steps for computation.

Tags: linear-algebra, fibonacci-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I'm struggling with the proof, that $\gcd\left(F_{n+1},F_n\right)$ takes exactly $n-1$ iteration steps. I'm not quite sure how to start - any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: How about actually doing an example, say $\gcd(F_9,F_8)$ and seeing what happens?

Comment: Think about how Fibonacci numbers are defined (and euclid's)...

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I totally understand it now. My only problem right now is how to write it down correctly. Is this ok?
1) Prove that two consecutively Fibonacci numbers have the remainder of 1. $F_{n+1} - F_n < F_n$
$F_n+F_{n-1}-F_n < F_n$
$F_{n-1} < F_n$ (which is correct)
2) Since the def of $F_n$ is $F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ we get $F_{n-1} = F_{n+1} - F_n$.

The next row in the gcd is calculated with $F_{n+1}-F_n$ which is the previous Fibonacci number $F_{n-1}$. Therefore with every iteration we get the prior Fibonacci number and therefore we have $n-1$ iteration steps.

Comment: Well, that's by the Euclidean algorithm.